# regex expression to preg_replace data:image(anything)"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

what is the regex that matches the following sequence:

```
data:image(any number of characters except of doublequotes)"
```

So the match starts with "data:image" (it can be in any part of the string, beginning, middle) then it is followed by 0 or more anything characters except of " which is the end of the match.

I want to use it in preg_replace so i can "strip" this unwanted series of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First match the literal text `data:image`, then zero or more characters that aren't `"` then `"`.

`data:image[^"]*"`

Answer (score 1):

if you want just the data:image:

```
$string = preg_replace('/data:image[^"]*"$/', 'data:image"', $string);
```

If you want just the other part:

```
$string = preg_replace('/data:image([^"]*)"$/', '\1', $string);
```